# How can I browse an XSS infected Joomla website for rebuilding purposes without being infected?

Tags: security, joomla

Both the web files and the database have been tampered pointing to malicious JavaScript. They have tasked me to rebuild their site, but I would like to be able to view the site if possible to get at the content and view the site as they had a lot of pages. Since I didn’t originally build the site I don’t know the structure of the content.

I don’t have to repair the site; I just need to rebuild it with the CMS of my choice. I don’t know anything about the Joomla database, or know if I can even get access to it to be able to start there.

I originally thought using a virtual machine would be OK for this, but I wasn’t sure if I would be risking my host machine as well using this method. I would of course turn off JavaScript but I was hoping someone else may have been already been down this road and might be able to offer some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just FTP to their host, pull it off and get it working on a machine with no connection?

If you were really paranoid. I don't think an XSS infected site would do too much damage to a properly protected machine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My paranoid answer:

It's a great idea to turn off Javascript.  I would get an extension like Noscript for Firefox or Notscript for Chrome.  I use these Noscript regularly, and it makes it easy to see what Javascript is coming from where.

Secondly, your idea with a VM is good, but take it a step further and run Linux in that VM.  Linux can be infected, but it is rare to see something that will infect Linux.

Regular expressions and HTML parsers can also be your friends.  Script something that can scan files looking for things like script tags and especially iframes.  That way you can get an idea of files that have been corrupted and what is calling to where.

One other less likely gotcha is malicious executables or scripts disguised as something innocent like a JPEG, PDFs, etc.  If you download and open files off of that machine, make sure it is at least onto your VM with no network connectivity.

Get server logs if you can; perhaps your assailant was sloppy and let some clue about their activities.  Perhaps run Wireshark on a second machine to look for things calling out to strange domains.  This may be excessive, but I find it to be a fun exercise. :)

Also things like [Virustotal](http://www.virustotal.com) and [Threat Expert](http://www.threatexpect.com) can be your friends if you think you have a malicious file or you see malicious activity.  Better to be paranoid than compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning this type of stuff up isn't exactly rocket science.  You just need to get a connection to the backing database server and run a couple queries to kill the xss stuff out of the stored content.

You'd do your client a great service by starting off doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

The VM idea is a good one. krs1 suggests running Linux which is an even better idea as almost all trojans that get downloaded are for Windows. If you run [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) while you use the site so you can see what the network traffic looks like and what URLs are being requested, etc. If you run it in a Linux VM though you'll probably only get half the picture since any exploit worth the oxygen it took to keep the programmer alive while it was written will check what platform you're on and only download when you're on an exploitable one.

But I digress, you're rebuilding a website, not doing malware analysis (which is more fun IMO). Once you identify and remove the offending content you should be good. See if you can find out what the exploit was that got them and work with their IT guy if they have one so steps can be taken to mitigate it from happening again.